# Hashset as constructor argument in Java

Tags: java, constructor, hashset

is there any way I can declare constructor to take HashSet as one of arguments and then pass HashSet value directly as argument during object initialization?
I mean something like this:

```
public class Order {
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();
    public Order (???) {
    this.products = ???
    }
}
```

and then, while initializing object:

```
Order order = new Order("product1", "product2", "product3");
```

is it possible?

Comment: Did you checkout all the `HashSet` constructors, to create an object and pass it to the constructor?

Answer (score 5):

You can use varargs :

```
public class Order {
    private Set<Product> products;
    public Order (Product... products) {
       this.products = new HashSet<Product> (Arrays.asList(products));
    }
}
```

But then you pass to the constructor Product instances :

```
Order order = new Order(new Product("product1"), new Product("product2"), new Product("product3"));
```

Comment: that's something like what I would like to achieve - but is it possible, to pass already existing objects instead of creating new ones?

Comment: @JarosławRewers Of course you can pass already existing `Product` instances.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something like:

```
public class Order {
    private final Set<String> strings;

    public Order(final Set<String> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }

    public Order(final String... strings) {
        this(toSet(strings));
    }

    private static Set<String> toSet(String[] strings) {
        final Set<String> ss = new HashSet<>();
        for (final String s : strings) {
            if (!ss.add(s)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate string " + s);
            }
        }
        return ss;
    }
}
```

This takes a [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) argument, which allows you to invoke the constructor as you would like.

It also checks for duplicates during initialization, I would suggest that duplicates are an error; but you could just log it and carry on.

Answer (score 0):

The above looks to me like you want a constructor taking [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) of `String` type, and then create the `HashSet` via those varargs.

A `HashSet` can't be created via varargs, so perhaps create the set and then add each element in turn. Or create a collection of those vararg elements, and then construct the `HashSet` directly from that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use the HashSet in the constructor, I would do something like this in the constructor:

```
public Order (HashSet<String> myHashSet)
```

Then, whenever you want to initialise it, call it this way:

```
Order order = new Order(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("product1", "product2")));
```

It's not very time efficient, but it works.